# Setting null value to Integer column field in Prepared Statement Setter

Tags: java, db2

Till I know, the correct way to do this is:

```
ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

However, on execution, my database column value is showing 4 instead of null.

On checking found that 4 is the static constant value for Types INTEGER.

Where could be the issue ?

Is it related to driver ?

The database is DB2.

Comment: One obvious thing to try is calling `ps.setNull(1, 3);` and seeing whether that then shows a value of 3...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is a trigger that modifies the data while inserting or updating.